# AWS EKS | EC2 mode pricing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-eks

I am planning to migrate a monolithic application to AWS EKS in EC2 mode. According to my understating the total cost is cluster price + EC2 instance price( worker nodes). But according to EKS user guide, EKS control plane consists of at least two API server nodes and three etcd nodes. Do I have to pay for those instances as well ?. In other words, is the total cost **cluster cost+EC2 instance cost(worker nodes)+control plane instance cost** ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about product or service pricing are off topic as explained in [Are questions on prices or support of developer services on topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274576) and [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745).

Answer (score 1):

No, the control plane cost includes the resources required to provide the control plane.

The [AWS EKS pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/pricing) page at the current time makes no reference to any costs associated with control plane instances.